# how to interpret event data ethereum

Tags: web3js, logs

I was able to use the [EtherScan api](https://etherscan.io/apis#logs) to get an array with event logs. Now I need to read from the data stored inside.

The event data exists out of: `uint256, uint256, uint256, address, address, string`.

I can do the following [web3](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#hextonumber) function: 
`web3.utils.hexToNumber(hex)` for the uint's and [hexToUtf8](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#hextoutf8) for the strings.

However I have 2 problems:

1. There's no web3 function `hexToAddress`. How can I do this?
2. I'm not sure how to split the event data with a web3 function or other method.

This is an example of the event data:

`"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"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could also use web3 directly using the `web3.eth.abi.decodeParameters(typesArray, hexString)` function:

In your case it would look like this:

```
web3.eth.abi.decodeParameters(['uint256', 'uint256', 'uint256', 'address', 'address', 'string'], '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')
```

Read more at https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-abi.html#decodeparameters.

Comment: I think the second parameter (the data) needs to be a string?

Comment: And also, the first parameters is an array of strings. If you edit that I'll mark it as correct! Thanks so much btw!!!

Comment: BTW, I have this error in node: `throw new Error('Couldn\'t decode '+ name +' from ABI: 0x'+ param.rawValue);` any idea?

Answer (score 1):

there is a lib for event log parsing from ConsenSys, the [abi-decoder](https://github.com/ConsenSys/abi-decoder)

Comment: great lib, thank you! I also used it in other places now :)